# Pixel 5 vibrates once when turned face down

Tags: vibration, google-pixel-5

My phone has this irritating behaviour. When I turn it face down, after a second or so it does a couple of quick vibrations.

It often confuses me into thinking that I have received a notification just after putting it down, so I pick it up, nope, put it down, it vibrates again...

Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**This is a side effect of [the "Flip to Shhh" feature](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/7443425#flip_to_shhh&zippy=%2Csee-how-to-place-your-phone-face-down).**

The setting page states,

> To turn on Do Not Disturb, place your phone face down on a flat surface. *You'll feel a subtle vibration when Do Not Disturb turns on.*

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

The feature can be accessed from Settings - System - Gestures - Flip to Shhh.

Comment: Huh...I had no idea that turned on DND! That probably explains why I have missed some calls in the past. God, what an impossible feature to discover - when you flip it back over it disables DND, so you would have no idea it ever did that.

Comment: Its not a new feature - but a lot of the features of modern phones could be considered "hidden" since there is no manual included anymore (they would quickly be outdated anyway)

Comment: @SteveBennett Lay on your back and look up at your phone?  Or does it also use the proximity sensor? (I don't seem to have this feature)

Comment: @Izkata I have a Pixel 3.  It will "Flip to Shhh" when hovering, face down, about an inch or two above a flat surface.  So I would guess that it uses the front-facing cameras to help.